# How to automate Packer AMI builds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-ami

I built and provisioned a AMI using packer and amazon-ebs.

I need to rebuild the AMI weekly. Is there a simple solution for this? Do I need a separate ec2 for jenkins or is that overkill? Would any CI tool be good for this or is there more simple approach? My packer ami code is hosted on github.

In addition, I create a new ec2 instance from AMI and tear down old one weekly. Whats the best way to schedule ec2 tear-downs and rebuilds automatically?

So 2 issues:

1. Weekly rebuild of AMI
2. Weekly rebuild of ec2 based on rebuilt AMI

Im not experienced with any devops things so please excuse me.

Comment: Your second point will doesn't feel like a best practice. You can't rebuild an EC2 based on the updated AMI. Only replace is possible.

Comment: Okay then automatically terminate an instance at a set time and spin up a new one based on the new AMI

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the only task where you want to use an automation server. In other case, I will suggest you create a Jenkins or any other automation server. It all depends on your need.

To automate this single task, you don't necessarily need an automation server. The one method I'm going to demonstrate is one among many ways you can do it. Below are the AWS resources you require.

1. A Docker image where `packer`, `aws cli`, and any other dependencies installed.
2. An ECS task configured using the image in #1.
3. A CloudWatch schedule expression to trigger the ECS task periodically, in this case weekly.

Your docker image should be configured such that container execution does the rebuild of the AMI. You can write a `bash` script for this and configure the same as the container entry point.

The second point, rebuild of EC2 server is not a best practice. You should have a separate process in place to apply the AMI changes to respective instances. However, you can do this by scheduling a lambda function which will terminate and launch a new instance.

I know this is a broad answer and there are many other ways to do the same.